# How to show form fields on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I've been working on this for weeks now and I can't seem to get the hang of this.  I'm trying to show the hidden fields only when the previous fields are entered.  Here's my example code:

HTML

```
<form>
    <div id="group1">
        <label>Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field1" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field2" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 3:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field3" />
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="group2">
        <label>Field 4:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field4" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 5:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field5" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 6:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field6" />
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="group3">
        <label>Field 7:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field7" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 8:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field8" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 9:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field9" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#group2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#group3 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#group1').find('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    CheckSubmit();
});
    function CheckSubmit() {
        var x = true;
        $('#group1').find('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                x = false;
                return;
            }
        });

    if (x) {
        $('#group2').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('#group3').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('#group2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $('#group3').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
        CheckSubmit();
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Can someone please assist?

Comment: Please name your variable (x) with useful variable names it will make your code much more readable.  Even in test code

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit. I stored the relevant selectors in variables, so you don't need to do a lot of re-querying every time something changes.

Here's the updated code:

**JavaScript**

```
var inputs = $('#group1').find('input[type="text"]');
var hidden = $('#group2, #group3');

inputs.keyup(function() {
    var test = true;

    inputs.each(function(key, value) {
        if (!$(this).val().length) {
            test = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    hidden.css('visibility', ( test ? 'visible' : 'hidden' ) );
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/kd3yLgqL/)

Comment: I tried but the fields disappear once you hit enter/submit

Comment: Case 1: If you want the code to be executed after a refresh with set values, simply call `inputs.trigger('change');` like in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2yb9yy2/) - Case 2: You want to prevent that the form is send, use this: `$('form').submit(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });` as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pm1ybnyq/).

Comment: Thanks but there isn't a set value for these fields.  this is an example so fields 1 would be first name, field 2 last name, etc..

Comment: Please explain, what you're trying to achieve, that still isn't working.

Comment: sorry for not being clear.  I want a form to where parts of the form is split.  group 2 and 3 will remain hidden until the previous fields in group 1 are entered.  I had it set before to where you will need to click a button in order to access the rest of the form.  I have more to say.  i want to show you something

Comment: I had it set initially as a button controlling it but now I'm trying to do it on keyup only

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can of course use it with key up as well, [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/5qt58n0v/).

Comment: @Military911 Don't miss to put the code into `$(document).ready()`. Maybe that's why it's not working on your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more dynamic by checking the inputs in the current div and if they all have a value, then show the next div (if there is one).

If they clear a value, then hide all the later divs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // you can restrict this to inputs in a specific div or just any input
    $('#group1 input').on('keyup', function () {
        var parentDiv = $(this).closest('div')
        var hasValues = parentDiv.find('input').filter(function() {
            return this.value == '';
        }).length == 0;

        if(hasValues) {
            //parentDiv.next().css('visibility', 'visible'); // show just the next section
            parentDiv.nextAll().css('visibility', 'visible'); // show all later sections
        } else {
            parentDiv.nextAll().css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rwoc66vf/3/)

Comment: I like the way this is working in your demo.  How can I get it to work to show both hidden divs at the same time?  So div 2 and 3 will show once fields in div 1 are filled?

Comment: just change `parentDiv.next()` to `parentDiv.nextAll()` to get all the later ones.

Comment: Thanks and I should've told you that there isn't a set value for these fields.  this is an example so fields 1 would be first name, field 2 last name, etc..

Comment: I'm trying to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/mjreno/1xxshcof/71/ but on keyup only, no button

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick pen with a solution. It may not be the prettiest but it get's it done. Basically on every keyup event I check `#group1`'s children for their value length and if they all have a length that's more than 0 I change a flag in an array. If all 3 flags are true I show `#group2`.

[Here's the pen](http://codepen.io/thecodethinker/pen/EHLpB)

```
$('#group2').hide();
$('#group3').hide();

$('#group1').keyup(function() {

  var flags = {
    0: false,
    1: false,
    2: false
  }

  $('#group1 > input').each(function(i, ele) {
    if(ele.value.length !== 0)
      {
        flags[i] = true;

      }
  });

  if(flags[0] && flags[1] && flags[2])
    {
      $('#group2').show();
    }
});

$('#group2').keyup(function() {

  var flags = {
    0: false,
    1: false,
    2: false
  }

  $('#group2 > input').each(function(i, ele) {
    if(ele.value.length !== 0)
      {
        flags[i] = true;

      }
  });

  if(flags[0] && flags[1] && flags[2])
    {
      $('#group3').show();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thank you.  Can you make it to where the form fields stay shown after submit?

Comment: That's easy. Just take out the `else` clause after the if statements and BAM!! you're all set

Comment: i took out the else and it still hides

Comment: it doesn't hide on the pen. try taking out the css

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you want to show the fields in #group2/-3 if all the fields in the previous fields have a value. Using a few data-*-attributes (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)), you can create a handler like this (if you prefer: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/wjq2kkmk/), containing a more complete example):

```js
$('[data-nextgroup] [type=text]').on('keyup', function (e){
  var fieldgroup = $(this.getAttribute('data-group'))
     ,fields = fieldgroup.find('[type=text]')
     ,canshow = fields.length === 
                 fields.filter( function (i,el) { return el.value.length; } ).length;
  void( canshow && $(fieldgroup.attr('data-nextgroup')).fadeIn() );
});
```

```css
[data-hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group1" data-nextgroup="#group2">
        <label>Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field1" data-group="#group1"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field2" data-group="#group1"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Field 3:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field3" data-group="#group1"/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" data-nextgroup="#group3" data-hidden>
        <label>Field 4:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field4" data-group="#group2"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Field 5:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field5" data-group="#group2"/>
        <br/>
        <label>Field 6:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field6" data-group="#group2"/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="group3" data-groups data-hidden>
        <label>Field 7:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field7" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 8:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field8" />
        <br/>
        <label>Field 8:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field9" />
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
```